# Is there a way Unity to constructor inject both registered type and concrete value

Tags: c#, unity-container

I defined 3 interfaces and 3 classes accordingly. Class A depends on interface B, interface B depends on interface C and a concrete class. My sample codes look like

```
public interface IA
{
}

public class A : IA
{
    private IB b;

    public A(IB b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public interface IB
{
}

public class B : IB
{
    private IC c;
    private string myValue;

    public B(IC c, string myValue)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
}

public interface IC
{
}

public class C : IC
{
}
```

The special thing is class B, the constructor requires both type and a string (concrete value).

```
        using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
        {
            container.RegisterType<IB, B>()
                .RegisterType<IA, A>()
                .RegisterType<IC, C>();

            IA a = container.Resolve<IA>();
        }
```

How shall I define in code to instruct container to inject both IC and a string value to class B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in an InjectionConstructor to your registration.

```
container.RegisterType<IB, B>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IC>(), "myvalue-value"));
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) provides a detail on injecting values into a registered object.  It is called an InjectionConstructor and provides the means you are looking for.  Not too hard at all.  Much you can do with Unity.

Comment: +1 because you link to the help page describing everything in detail.